# inverse normalization of output patch of autoencoder

Tags: image-processing, normalization, autoencoder

I have coded for denoising autoencoder following the approach in deeplearning.net to denoise gray scale image. I have used sigmoid and tanh activation functions. Training dataset consists of 1,00,000 patches extracted from a gray scale dataset ( decsai.ugr.es/cvg/dbimagenes). As a part of preprocessing the images, I am normalizing the extracted patches by rescaling(dividing the patch by 255), subtracting the mean and dividing by the std deviation. The output test patch I get after passing through the autoencoder is a normalized one (second attached image). How do I get back the original grayscale patch (Inverse normalization). Please suggest any possible solution. Thanks in advance.

Input image:

[image: Input image]

output normalized patch:

[image: output normalized patch]